# Telegram : How can show welcome message for new join bot

Tags: telegram-bot

I create new bot in telegram bot ,and do steps like here :-

```
https://core.telegram.org/bots#
```

But now i need when any new user join in my bot, i need to show him welcome message.

How can do that ?

Comment: can you clarify who is joining where? Is bot joins a group chat OR is bot welcomes new comers to group OR just a user starts to use your bot?

Answer (score 14):

Use `/setdescription` and `/setabouttext` [@BotFather](https://telegram.me/botfather) commands

Answer (score 5):

You must send these commands to @BotFather

```
/setdescription
```

then send your bot id like:

```
@example_bot
```

and send you welcome message

```
Welcome to my bot
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to implement the `/start` command in your bot realization - set the welcome message.

And you should describe this command in chat with @BotFather via `/setcommands` for your bot.

After that when user adds your bot, the `/start` command fires automatically, and he will see the message you implemented.